# Can Git merge changes from a disk copy (not a clone) of a personal repository?

Tags: git, git-extensions

I started using Git Extensions with no prior knowledge of Git. I created a personal repository for a project I was given that was not under source control. I made a bunch of commits, and then *copied* (instead of cloning, which I now see is what I should have done) the source directory and gave it to the person who gave me the project in the first place.

Since then we have both made further changes to our respective local repositories, and we are planning to merge them in the near future. Is this possible, given that I didn't properly clone my repository before giving it to the other person?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloning and copying are the same thing (assuming you included the .git directory in the copy) except that remotes are not configured. You can merge them exactly as you would a cloned repository, save that you'll have to configure a remote to fetch from in one of your copies.

Answer (score 2):

One of you wants to make a patch and give it to the other.  Then you need to create a central repo of the patched repository and both clone it and start working from that.  Keep in mind that when you perform that patch you may have conflicts that you will have to resolve.

Here's a tutorial on patching.

http://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. A clone (that is a clone with a working directory) is almost a copy. I say almost, because a clone will not create a copy of any untracked files.

So, for discussion's sake, if we assume that your working tree did not have any untracked files, or that your .gitignore file was tracked (and that it included all the necessary entries), then a copy is the same as a clone.

That said, from a merging point of view you can merge between the two repositories.